# Entendendo o Retorno automático do PagSeguro

Tags: php

estou tendo problema em entender o retorno automático do PagSeguro.

Estou seguindo o seguinte tutorial:

```
http://blogpagseguro.com.br/2012/05/tutorial-pagseguro-entendendo-o-retorno-automatico/
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Nesse tutorial diz que o `pagseguro`, assim que o cliente efetua o pagamento no `checkout`, ele é redirecionado ao site e junto (Não Sei como) é enviado um $_POST como os dados da transação.

Pede também para, ao receber esse `$_POST`, enviar de volta via `cUrl` o `$_POST` para verificação junto ao PagSeguro que responderá se é válida ou inválida esse envio do `$_POST`.

Até aí sem problemas. Mas então surge a dúvida: Esse retorno :

```
if ($result == "VERIFICADO") {
    //O post foi validado pelo PagSeguro.
    Update_Transacao($transacaoID,$referencia,$TipoPagamento,$dataTransacao,$status);


} else if ($result == "FALSO") {
    //O post não foi validado pelo PagSeguro.
} else {
    //Erro na integração com o PagSeguro.
}
```

é entregue pela `XML` ou é enviado um `$_GET` de forma diferente depois?

Porque se for enviado por `XML`, logo, o `script` nunca chegará a entrar no bloco abaixo:

```
} else {
    // POST não recebido, indica que a requisição é o retorno do Checkout PagSeguro.
    // No término do checkout o usuário é redirecionado para este bloco.
    ?>
    <h3>Obrigado por efetuar a compra.</h3>
    <?php
}
```

Pois ao entrar no bloco

```
if (count($_POST) > 0) {
```

Logo é feita a chamada à `API` para validar o `$_POST` como abaixo:

```
// POST recebido, indica que é a requisição do `NPI`.
$npi = new PagSeguroNpi();
$result = $npi->notificationPost();
```

Estou certo?

Se estou, a validação de deu certo ou não, deveria ficar dentro de:

```
if ($result == "VERIFICADO") {
    //O post foi validado pelo PagSeguro.
    Update_Transacao($transacaoID,$referencia,$TipoPagamento,$dataTransacao,$status);


} else if ($result == "FALSO") {
    //O post não foi validado pelo PagSeguro.
} else {
    //Erro na integração com o PagSeguro.
}
```

e não de:

```
} else {
    // POST não recebido, indica que a requisição é o retorno do Checkout PagSeguro.
    // No término do checkout o usuário é redirecionado para este bloco.
    ?>
    <h3>Obrigado por efetuar a compra.</h3>
    <?php
}
```

Estou meio confuso.

Comment: Você não esta usando a integração com checkout transparente ne?

Comment: não, estou fazendo na mão mesmo